# Singular or plural verbs with idioms that start with singular articles

Tags: grammar, idioms

I wonder which verb form, singular or plural, is grammatically correct in the following sentence:
"Education and welfare is/are a matter of concern to us."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bread and butter is/are my breakfast?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198072/) And [Is it: My apples and orange are/is wrong?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/) and [“Is” or “are” with two nouns and one of them being modified by an adjective?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/), among others

Comment: @FumbleFingers OT, but I feel that I should point out that bread and butter are my bread and butter.  And they're definitely my jam.

Comment: The short answer is ... _both_. The longer answer is that **you**  the communicator are able to focus attention on the two separate issues if you choose _are_, or on the combined field (perhaps administered by a single government department in some cases) if you choose _is_.

Comment: @idunno: But surely bread and butter ***is*** essential when you're having fish and chips - how else would you be able to make a [chip butty](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chip+butty+picture&oq=chip+butty+picture&aqs=chrome..69i57.3289j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8)? :)

Comment: GMWAS  that's one of the grossest thing's I've ever seen. But then, I don't eat potatoes, bread, or butter.